# Python.Pandas Замена отсутствующих значений, на значения из словаря

Tags: python, pandas

Есть 2 датафрейма, как мне заменить отсутствующие значения в первом соответствующие во втором:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',9.1], ['b',None], ['c',None], ['d',9.2], ['e',7.5]], columns=['x','y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',9.1], ['b',6.3], ['c',6.1]], columns=['x','y'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.fillna(df2)
```

df:

```
   x    y
0  a  9.1
1  b  6.3
2  c  6.1
3  d  9.2
4  e  7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так что ли:

```
mask = df['y'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'y'] = df.merge(df2, on='x').loc[mask, 'y_y']
df
```

| index | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 9.1 |
| 1 | b | 6.3 |
| 2 | c | 6.1 |
| 3 | d | 9.2 |
| 4 | e | 7.5 |